# Should I install BOTH patches ? SUPEE 7616 AND SUPEE 7405

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, usps

As we all know Magento released `SUPEE 7405` Security patch. As well `SUPEE 7616` (related to USPS changes), I am not sure if it is also security related. But should I install it for my Canadian store if I do not use USPS?

Answer (score 2):

As it says on their web-site:
https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-supee-7616-with-or-without-ssh/

> This patch is only required if you are using USPS. USPS made several changes in their Rate, Services and Package names on 17th January 2016. You can install the update by installing this patch in your Magento.

However, should you need to use USPS in the future you can install both if they don't have conflicts with each other and apparently they don't.

Answer (score 2):

SUPEE-7405 is the [much needed security patch](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-7405), definitely install it.

SUPEE-7616 is the USPS service change patch, only install it if you use the US Postal Service to ship packages. And it contains no security related items, just some service name changes and discontinued service removals.